# Can you control Aero snap through speech recognition?

Tags: windows-7, aero, speech-recognition

Is there a command to snap a window to the left and right of the screen in Windows 7?

I have searched but not found anything (short of telling it to press <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>Left</kbd> or <kbd>Right</kbd>)?

Or some way to add a command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no Aero Snap shortcut built in to speech recognition and I am not aware of a way to add it / macro it.

You will probably have to do as you said and tell it to do Windows Key + Left/Right.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe **[Younicate Speech Recognition Commands](http://www.tucows.com/preview/515294)** works for you.

Powered by a sophisticated algorithm, Younicate launches commands from speech recognition without mistake nor training.

[image]

*Younicate is freeware.*